# Can I comment out a line in a .git/config file?

Tags: git, config

I have a `http.proxy` line on my repository configuration file that I would like to 'turn on and off' easily without having to remember and type again the whole configuration every time I'm behind or free from this proxied connection.

Another possibility would be to use this repository configuration file when I'm behind the proxy and when not, use a global/local configuration file without any proxy setup.

Answer (score 356, accepted):

Yes, you can comment lines out of Git config files using `#` or `;`.

From [the documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#_syntax):

> **Syntax**
>
> The syntax is fairly flexible and permissive; whitespaces are mostly ignored. The `#` and `;` characters begin comments to the end of line, blank lines are ignored.